# Official Server GUI in next Server release?

Tags: networking, server, gui, home-directory

I wonder if Ubuntu dev's do read this, but here is the thing.. I heard that Fedora Server gets an official GUI for server to use. I mean the Ubuntu community is most advanced.

Has Unity GUI invented 
Has Mobile OS and TV interface made.
Don't you guys think that it is time to make GUI for Ubuntu server? Perhaps in the next release, which is on LTS side is in 2019... How to imagine it? 
Look at QNAP, Asustor, sinology, they all use open source Linux and we in the Ubuntu community don't have an equivalent? If I controlled Linux development across the board, I would ask them to make a version of their OS's available to the public. You might say, use Amahi or something similar.. Well I can't because, my ISP is relaying all their other services on my fibre connection. Which means I  can't make these options work simply because I don't have DHCP access on my network, or shall I say full control of it. Don't judge my ISP they are nice guys, it's just they want their services to work uninterrupted and I see the reason why.. If say I mess up somewhere I couldn't call ambulance, police, or fire fighters in case of emergency... I don't want to become hostage of my home server's mood, if you know what I mean. I want things to  work somewhat independent...  I am sure people will understand me in a way...

Comment: The lack of a GUI is basically the difference between an Ubuntu desktop and an Ubuntu server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that Ubuntu Server runs without a GUI, is because an Ubuntu server is likely to run headless (no monitor, no keyboard, no mouse).  The advantage, is that this keeps hardware requirements lower.  Besides, administrating tasks such as a file server/e-mail server/firewall/etc. isn't going to require a GUI.

If, however, you really want a server that runs with a GUI, then you can follow this guide:

http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-gui-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-gnome/

Hope this helps.